# Phonegap - whitelist rejection in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I have searched and found that in cordova.plist we need to add a row (contains url) in external host.

I did this but can not find any thing working.

I tried code

```
    <key>ExternalHosts</key>
    <array>
        <string>localhost</string>
        <string>https://www.google.com</string>
    </array>
```

but its not worthy !

What to do ?

Comment: have you tried googling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the https and just leave the domain name in the whitelist

Answer (score 0):

The hard part is done. Now it's just like making a simple HTML/css/js web app -- just put all of your code inside the index.html that you created in the Getting Started Tutorial.

Examples: [API Reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/)

[iOS Phonegap Plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS) on github

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you are not able to access your localhost so change your localhost with your IP address and accessible port.

Or if you want you can change it to "*" so that it can access all external url.

```
<key>ExternalHosts</key>
    <array>
        <string>*</string>
    </array>
```